# Unicorn error adding listener

Tags: ruby, docker, listener, unicorn

I am having issues getting a unicorn server up and running. I try to run unicorn using:

```
bundle exec unicorn -c /var/www/docninja/unicorn.rb -E development -D -p 8080
```

I get the following error:

```
I, [2015-04-14T23:54:52.117609 #123]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/var/www/docninja/tmp/sockets/unicorn.docninja.sock fd=10
I, [2015-04-14T23:54:52.118624 #123]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=11
I, [2015-04-14T23:54:52.119553 #123]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2015-04-14T23:54:52.127642 #123]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2015-04-14T23:54:52.129109 #126]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=126
I, [2015-04-14T23:54:52.129559 #126]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
F, [2015-04-14T23:59:07.536943 #130] FATAL -- : error adding listener addr=/var/www/docninja/tmp/sockets/unicorn.docninja.sock
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:152:in `bind_listen': socket=/var/www/docninja/tmp/sockets/unicorn.docninja.sock specified but it is not a socket! (Argument$
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:242:in `listen'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `block in bind_new_listeners!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `bind_new_listeners!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:138:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Here is my unicorn.rb file located in my main app directory (/var/www/docninja):

```
app_dir = "/var/www/docninja"

# Set the working application directory
working_directory app_dir

# Unicorn PID file location
pid "#{app_dir}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Path to logs
stderr_path "#{app_dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{app_dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

# Path to socket file for nginx
listen "#{app_dir}/tmp/sockets/unicorn.docninja.sock", :backlog => 64

worker_processes 1

timeout 30
```

All the paths here seem to be correct because it finds the sockets directory and the logs are where they should be; however, it just is not able to add some listener on that?

I'm not sure if this helps but I am also setting this up in a Docker container using a Dockerfile.

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: How are you running your container? I.e. are you using BootToDocker? I've heard there are problems with the extra layer of indirection caused by BootToDocker.  (Also double-check the permissions on that socket, and remove it if it's already there.)

Comment: Thanks! I am, indeed, using Boot2Docker - will try pushing to docker on Digital Ocean and see if that works better there. For the permissions, would I just use chmod to set the permissions on the socket folder?

Comment: My guess is that the socket is in a remote folder that is shared from your Mac. If you move it to somewhere that is "local to Linux", it should work fine.  You can try chmod, but I imagine the error would be different if that were the case. Removing the file might help if the file got created as a non-socket somehow.